# UnmarshalJSON results in stack overflow

Tags: go

This works: http://play.golang.org/p/-Kv3xAguDR.

This results in a stack overflow: http://play.golang.org/p/1-AsHFj51O.

I fail to understand why. What is the correct way use the `JSONUnmarshaler` interface in this case?

```
package main

import (
    //"bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type T interface {
    Printer()
}

type A struct{ JA string }

func (t A) Printer() { fmt.Print("A") }

/*
func (t *A) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    i := A{}
    dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err := dec.Decode(&i); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    i.Printer()
    *t = i
    return nil
}
*/

var vI []T

func main() {
    vI = []T{&A{}}
    get()
}

func get() {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader("[{\"JA\":\"OK\"}]"))
    if err := dec.Decode(&vI); err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    for _, v := range vI {
        v.Printer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
dec.Decode(&i)
```

will call your `UnmarshalJSON`, which in turn will call `Decode`, and so on. If you need to unmarshal your JSON and then do something with it, one neat technique is to declare a local type, unmarshal your data into it, and then convert back to your desired type:

```
// Type a has no UnmarshalJSON.
type a A
i := a{}
dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(data))
if err := dec.Decode(&i); err != nil {
    return err
}
// Convert back to A.
tt := A(i)
tt.Printer()
*t = tt
// ...
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/HWamV3MbvW.

The type `a` has no methods (so no stack overflow), but is [convertible](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to `A`.