# Golang: Type assign with another struct

Tags: go, methods, struct, embedding

So I have this example here:
[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/h_SojewkBG)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Circle struct{}

func (c Circle) Something() {
    fmt.Println("something")
}

type Rectangle struct {
    Circle
}

func (a Rectangle) SomethingElse() {
    fmt.Println("SomethingElse")
}

type Form Rectangle

func main() {
    c := Form{}
    c.Circle.Something()
    c.SomethingElse()
}
```

I don't understand why I can call `Something` from the embedded `Circle`, but cannot call `Somethingelse` from the `Rectangle` within the `Form` type. Also I don't understand what benefit I get when I declare a type of some other type, like here in `Form`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This:

```
type Form Rectangle
```

Creates a *new* type named `Form`, having `Rectangle` as its *underlying* type.

This means that the fields of `Rectangle` (which is a struct) will be defined for `Form` as well.

But methods are bound to a specific type. When you create a new type (`Form`), that new type will not have any of the methods of its underlying type, so you can't call `c.SomethingElse()` as `SomethingElse()` is a method of the `Rectangle` type.

`c.Circle.Something()` works, because `c.Circle` is a field of type `Circle`, and `Something()` is a method of the `Circle` type.

If you want to call the `Rectangle.SomethingElse()` method, that requires a value of type `Rectangle` (the receiver type is `Rectangle`). Since underlying type of `Form` is `Rectangle`, you can simply obtain a value of type `Rectangle` from a value of type `Form` using a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
Rectangle(c).SomethingElse() // This works
```

The benefit of creating a new type is that so you can create / add your own methods for it. A common example is implementing the [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) interface. Let's say you have a slice of something, e.g. `[]Rectangle`, or a slice of some type which you have no control over (beause it's part of another package – and methods for a type can only be defined in the same package). If you want to sort this slice, you create a new type for which you can define methods, the methods of `sort.Interface`, e.g.:

```
type SortRectangle []Rectangle

func (s SortRectangle) Len() int           { return len(s) }
func (s SortRectangle) Less(i, j int) bool { return s[i] <some-logic> s[j] }
func (s SortRectangle) Swap(i, j int)      { s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i] }
```

The `sort.Sort()` function is able to sort any values that implement `sort.Interface`. The `[]Rectangle` does not, but we just created a new type `SortRectangle` which does. And if we have a value of type `[]Rectangle`, we can convert it to `SortRectangle` because the former is the underlying type of the latter, and by doing a conversion, we have a value of type `SortRectangle` which can be passed to `sort.Sort()`, in order to have it sorted:

```
rs := []Rectangle{}
// Sort rs:
sort.Sort(SortRectangle(rs))
```

Note that a conversion like the above `SortRectangle(rs)` only changes the runtime type information, it does not change the memory representation of `rs`, so it's pefectly *safe* and *efficient*.

If you want the new type to have the methods of the "old" type, then use embedding. See Ainar-G's answer. In fact, you already did this by embedding `Circle` in `Rectangle`: the type `Rectangle` has a method `Something()`, because `Something()` is a method of `Circle`:

```
Rectangle{}.Something()  // Prints "something"
```

Comment: Thx for the great explanation!

Answer (score 7):

A simple rule in Go. If you want the type's methods, do

```
type A struct { B }
```

and if you *don't* want the type's methods, do

```
type A B
```

Why do we need the second form? *Interfaces,* for example. Sometimes we *don't* want a value to satisfy an interface, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34859671/1892060). Other times you just need the types and not its methods.

Go gives you the possibility to get the type that is the same, but with an empty method set.

Answer (score 1):

The whole (and only) reason to do `type Form Rectangle` is to define a *new* type with *different* methods. In your example: No methods. `c` is a Form and has no methods, it's only raison d'être is *not* having a `SomethingElse()` method.

But a `Form` still embeds a Circle which is accessible as `c.Circle` and which is a `Circle` so it obviousely has the method `Something()`.